# Timezone converttime with datetime parse

Tags: c#, datetime

I am having a service which was scheduled to run at specific time as follows

```
<add key="ScheduledTime" value="18:00" />
```

What I am trying is to convert it to `PST` zone as follows

```
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
scheduledTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Parse("18:00"), cstZone);
```

But I am still getting my system date instead of PST can some one tell me what I did wrong the following is working when I have the following code

```
DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(timeUtc, cstZone);
Console.WriteLine("The date and time are {0} {1}.", cstTime, cstZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(cstTime) ?                                         cstZone.DaylightName : cstZone.StandardName);
```

[image]

This is what I have

```
DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
 DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(timeUtc, cstZone);
Console.WriteLine("The date and time are {0} {1}.",cstTime,
cstZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(cstTime) ? cstZone.DaylightName : cstZone.StandardName);

DateTime cst = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Parse("18:00"), cstZone);
Console.Write(cst);
```

Comment: Which timezone to you expect "18:00" do be in? UTC or another timezone?

Comment: Time zone should be `PST` I am getting the time as `27-07-2017 10:07:00` instead of `26-07-2017 23:10:56`

Comment: Is my assumption correct that your local timezone is not PST?

Comment: Yes but when I have the following code in a console application giving me what I need `DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
            DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(timeUtc, cstZone);
            Console.WriteLine("The date and time are {0} {1}.",
                              cstTime,
                              cstZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(cstTime) ?
                                      cstZone.DaylightName : cstZone.StandardName);`

Comment: Please put the code into your *question* rather than comments, and give us output. Within the [mcve], please just hard-code the data rather than using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScheduledTime"]`, so it's easier to reproduce.

Comment: @Dotnet In your console app, you are converting UTC -> PST. In your first example, you are converting Local Time Zone -> PST.

Comment: You still haven't provided a [mcve] of it *not* working... and please show output just as text rather than as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone on the service is probably not what you expect. Print it and check:

```
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Comment: Updated the question can you check, you can see the first line is giving me exact date but when I am adding time and parsing it I am getting my system time

Comment: I am not sure I understand the output. In your code, you are writing to the output only one line (and one `date`) but your screenshot includes 2 lines and 2 `date`s.

Comment: You can check now

Comment: what is printed when you execute `Console.WriteLine(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName);` on your local machine and on your service machine?

Comment: I am not getting this `TimeZone`in intellisense and not getting the required using method is it a different class?

Comment: It is a different class. You can use also `TimeZoneInfo.Local` to check it. What is printed when you execute `Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.Local)` on your local machine and on your service machine?